# Swift Cocoa buttons not in place

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uikit

I'm new doing Cocoa Touch but I worked whit java swing, I made what I suppose draw to buttons on the screen, one on the left (green) and other on the right (blue), but I only see the blue one the other is missing. It's a class of a view with two buttons on it.

```
import UIKit

class MouseClick: UIView {
//MARK: Atributes
var clicks = [UIButton]()

//MARK: Initializer
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder){
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
   //let bounds = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds

    let button = UIButton()

    // x: start of x in frame,  y: start of y in frame width:half screen, height:full screen
    let leftButtonFrame = CGRect(x: frame.origin.x, y:frame.origin.y, width: frame.size.width/2.0, height:frame.size.height)
    // x: start of x in frame plus the half,  y: start of y in frame width:half screen, height:full screen
    let rigthButtonFrame = CGRect(x:  frame.origin.x + frame.size.width/2.0, y: frame.origin.y, width: frame.size.width/2.0, height: frame.size.height)

    //test action (only prints)
    button.addTarget(self, action: "clickAction:", forControlEvents: .TouchDown)

    clicks = [button, button]

    clicks[0].frame = leftButtonFrame
    clicks[1].frame = rigthButtonFrame

    clicks[0].backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    clicks[1].backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

    addSubview(clicks[0])
    addSubview(clicks[1])
}
override func layoutSubviews() {
    // Set butons(clicks) size, width:half screen, height:full screen
    let buttonSize = Int(frame.size.height)

    var buttonFrame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: frame.size.width/2.0, height: CGFloat(buttonSize))

    // set x position for every button in clixk

    for (index, button) in clicks.enumerate() {
        buttonFrame.origin.x = CGFloat(index) * frame.size.width/2.0
        button.frame = buttonFrame
    }
}
override func intrinsicContentSize() -> CGSize {
    let heigth = Int(frame.size.height)
    let width = Int(frame.size.width)
    return CGSize(width: width, height: heigth)
}
//MARK: Clicks actions
func clickAction(button: UIButton)
{
    var n = clicks.indexOf(button)!
    if n == 0
    {
        print("leftie")
    } else
    {
        print("rightie")
    }
}
}
```

the resulting image here,

[image: [enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCQNF.png)

Comment: Post screenshot if you can, also try using ViewDebugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you initialize only one button. The 'clicks' array contains two references pointing to the same Button. This is why you only see one on Screen.

```
let button = UIButton()
let button2 = UIButton()
```

.
.
.

```
clicks = [button, button2]
```

Now you have two buttons.